# Grass cmd file blocked by group strategy

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I encounter difficulties whenever I try to run any GRASS plugin from within QGIS (mainly) : it looks like my company has set up a group strategy preventing the call to .cmd files from programms.
This is only empiric guess since I am not really skilled with such strategies and I could be indeed wrong about the cause matching the symptom!

Anyway : here's the message grom the GRASS plugin (translated from french to english for a better understanding):

> Execution of
>   C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_3eb0b5419fcc4fcfb2518bc4d51d5a42\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd
>   ...  This programme is blocked by a group stategy. For further
>   information, contact your system administrator.

And I am quite upset about it since GRASS holds very usefull tools..

Does anyone have a workaround to have GRASS work in this penitentiary environnement?

Comment: Just guessing, would that help? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d86812fd-12cd-4bbf-84c5-b3509b63b355/this-program-is-blocked-by-group-policy?forum=winserverGP

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to access the required tool. Thus, I am rather looking for a workaround! Thanks for the link anyway.